# C++, having issues using const_iterator to make operator=

Tags: c++, const-iterator

There is a compilation error which occurs when I write the following:

```
const_iterator it = cp.begin();
```

`const_iterator` is my own class for `const iterator`.

 `cp` is an object of a class `ConjuntoPreguntas` (see below).

 The error is:

```
mainprueba.cpp:30:6: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘ConjuntoPreguntas::const_iterator’ and ‘ConjuntoPreguntas::iterator’)
  cit = CP.begin();
      ^
mainprueba.cpp:30:6: note: candidate is:
In file included from mainprueba.cpp:2:0:
conjuntopreguntas.h:258:21: note: ConjuntoPreguntas::const_iterator& ConjuntoPreguntas::const_iterator::operator=(const ConjuntoPreguntas::const_iterator&)
     const_iterator& operator=(const const_iterator& cit){
                     ^
conjuntopreguntas.h:258:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ConjuntoPreguntas::iterator’ to ‘const ConjuntoPreguntas::const_iterator&’
```

The code:

```
class ConjuntoPreguntas{
private:
    map<int,Pregunta> preguntas;

public:     
    class const_iterator;

    class iterator{
    private:
          map<int,Pregunta>::iterator it;

    public:
          iterator & operator++(){
           ++it;
          }

          iterator & operator--(){
           --it;
          }

          pair<const int,Pregunta> &operator *(){
           return *it;
          }

          bool operator ==(const iterator &i){
           return i.it==it;
          }   

          bool operator !=(const iterator &i){
           return i.it!=it;
          }

          friend class ConjuntoPreguntas;
          friend class const_iterator;
    };


    class const_iterator{
    private:
          map<int,Pregunta>::iterator it;
    public:
          const_iterator(){ 
          }

          const_iterator & operator++(){
           ++it;
          }

          const_iterator & operator--(){
           --it;
          }

          pair<const int,Pregunta> &operator *(){
           return *it;
          }

          bool operator ==(const const_iterator &i){
           return i.it==it;
          }   

          bool operator !=(const const_iterator &i){
           return i.it!=it;
          }

          const_iterator& operator=(const const_iterator& cit){
          }

          friend class ConjuntoPreguntas;

    };

    iterator begin(){
        iterator i;
        i.it=preguntas.begin();
        return i;
    }   

    iterator end(){
        iterator i;
        i.it=preguntas.end();
        return i;
    }
/* other code, irrelevant to the problem */                             
};
```

If anyone can help me, I will be very grateful.

Comment: The call to begin is returning an iterator (not const_iterator). There is no conversion defined from iterator to const_iterator in your code.

Comment: So many friends... iterator classes could be inherited, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Your most immediate problem is because you don't have a `const` version of `begin`:

```
   const_iterator begin() const
   {
        const_iterator i;
        i.it = preguntas.begin();
        return i;
    }
```

But then also your `const_iterator` class uses map's iterator which is going to result in another problem.

If you're writing a container-looking class, there's nothing for it but to write const-correct iterator and const_iterator classes and provide the const-correct members.

If however you are NOT writing a container, you may not want to do this. The best case is to provide a container-agnostic interface to the class, where for example you provide meaningful names rather than direct container access. Alternately provide const-only access via the map `const_iterator` (don't write your own iterator class).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fully encapsulate std container inside your class (daunting and usually unneccessary task) you need to make sure you also define all conversions. In particlar, standard container iterators have a constructor which creates const_iterator from iterator (but not the other way around!). You will have to create it yourselfa as well.

However, a much better design choice would be to simply expose the member `map` variable.

Comment: What do you mean by _expose_?

Comment: Just make your `preguntas` public.

Comment: It violates incapsulation principle. My thoughts: `const_iterator` could have access by value, and `iterator` by ref to `preguntas`.

Comment: @John_West, no more than opening iterator access to it. There is no difference (from incapsulation perspective) between giving full access through iterators or just exposing the variable.

Comment: but when exposing the variable `const_iterator` (and, what is more important, all other classes developed in the future) would have full access too. `iterator` could be the friend class, and all other could have an access by value only. What do you think?

Comment: Like I said, there is no need to go through all those pains. If you are giving the variable away anyways (by exposing non-const iterators to it) you might as well just expose the variable and yourself and the user of the class some typing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97320/discussion-between-john-west-and-sergeya).